# How to understand the modulo in all() function in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, boolean, generator, modulo

I know the modulo `%` in Python means to get the remainder, for example:

```
print 6 % 4            # 2, because 6 = 1 * 4 + 2
print 4 % 2            # 0, because 4 = 2 * 2 + 0
```

I also have learned the `all()` function is like the universal quantification, which return `True` if all the propositions are `True`, and its argument should be an itarable.

```
my_list = [True, True, True, True]
print all(my_list)                    # True
```

However I am stuck in understanding the following code:

```
test_num = [3,6,9]

print all (11 % i for i in test_num)        # True

for unknown in (11 % i for i in test_num):
    print unknown, type(unknown)            # 2 <type 'int'>
                                            # 5 <type 'int'>
                                            # 2 <type 'int'>
```

So, why I can get True value from the iterable whose items are all integers?

Thank you!

Comment: From doc:

>Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

Comment: @ahsanul So in this case, the iterable is seen as empty?

Comment: No, the iterable isn't seen as empty. The modulo operator returns a number, and if none of them are 0, `all` returns True. It is basically testing whether 11 is divisible by any numbers in `test_num`, and if it's divisible by neither, it returns True. Not very clear code though.

Comment: @L3viathan Yeah, it is what I am confused about. So the `all()` function interpret integer 0 as `False` and other integers as `True`?

Comment: To know more about what is True and what is False in python, read this https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Thanks a lot. I found during the process of learning Python, there are more and more unknown content  :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take an integer in a boolean context (for example in a condition, or explicitely through `bool`), it returns whether the integer is non-zero:

```
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(43)
True
```

So let's look at the code:

`(11 % i for i in test_num)` is a generator that unrolls to `11 % 3`, `11 % 6`, and `11 % 9`, which turn to `2`, `5`, and `2`. Since they're all non-zero, `all` returns `True`.

In effect, this returns `True` if and only if 11 is divisible by neither 3, 6, nor 9.

Answer (score 1):

Anything other than 0 is taken as true. Since there is no 0 in `test_num`, `all(test_num)` will return true.

Try this:

```
>>> test_num = [2,3,0]
>>> print all(test_num)
False
```

Apply the same logic to the for loop and you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you looked at help(all) ?

```
Help on built-in function all in module __builtin__:

all(...)
    all(iterable) -> bool

    Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
    If the iterable is empty, return True.
```

all() is working on Boolean and return a Boolean. So your integer are Transformed to Boolean, meaning any non zero value return True. So you will get False if any modulo return 0, else you get True.

```
>>> print all([False,True])
False
>>> print all([True,False])
False
>>> print all([True,True])
True
```